# Table column with duplicated text values

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a database table where a have a varchar(200) column.
This is a table with historical log information where about 99.9% of the rows in the table contains the same text message as another row in the table.
The size of that database and speed when searching is becoming a problem.

So I was thinking that I could move the varchar values to another table with unique text values and then have a reference to that table for every row in the first table, but before I change this, I would like to know if there is an easier way to do this?
For instance setting some property on my existing table column that would cause this behavior automatically. So that the database automatically maintains a table with unique texts. I realize that this would of cause have a big performance impact on delete operation but that is almost never done anyway.
Also I would really like to avoid changing the program that inserts into the log table.

I have been using MySQL but if another DB can do this it is also an option to change the database another one. (MariaDB or other?)

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to achieve here - normalising or increasing the speed?

Comment: Also if this is just a historical log, why are you logging in MySQL at first place?

Comment: My first objective is to reduce the size of the database. I need to search in the logs thats why I used a database. There is also time stamps and other colmuns in the data.

Comment: Why don't you just make separate tables on daily, weekly or monthly basis? Because you will reduce the size now, but what about it 3 months? Or 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no property or whatsoever that handles this for you, but you have a good idea there, putting the varchar data in a separate table. To do so, follow these steps.

1. Create your table holding your varchar data like this:

   `CREATE TABLE log_messages (id int auto_increment primary key, message varchar(200)) ENGINE = MyISAM ROW_FORMAT=FIXED;`
2. Insert your varchar data

   `INSERT INTO log_messages (message) 
   SELECT DISTINCT your_varchar_column
   FROM your_table;`
3. Add a new column in your original table to reference the new log_messages table

   `ALTER TABLE your_table ADD COLUMN message_id int not null;`
4. Create the reference

   `UPDATE your_table y INNER JOIN log_messages m ON y.your_varchar_column = m.message
   SET y.message_id = m.id;`
5. Then you can drop the varchar column from your table

   `ALTER TABLE your_table DROP COLUMN your_varchar_column;`

Now that you have that, I'm not sure why you're concerned about performance impact on delete operations. There's none.

Answer (score 1):

This is the right way to do normalisation, but my advice is instead of unique text go for number(integer).....

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I had to do it over, I would also do it that way. I just wanted to make sure I was not wasting time on something that the database could handle for me.